# Powershell error inside azure release pipeline yaml

Tags: powershell, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I converted Azure release pipeline classic pipeline to yaml with [yamlzr](https://github.com/f2calv/yamlizr/tree/main)
Powershell command is failing inside yaml file:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression in powershell inside azure release pipeline yaml

[image: azure pipeline error]

`$branch = $env:build_sourceBranch.substring($env:build_sourceBranch.indexOf('/', 5) + 1)`

1. I tried to use Build.SourceBranchName built-in variable but not working.
2. I tried to map it

```
 env:
            BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

I got (Line: 162, Col: 13): A mapping was not expected eror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with your script (lowercase variable) when using `Ubuntu-latest` agent in pipeline.

In DevOps Variable names are transformed to **uppercase**, and the characters "`.`" and " " are replaced by "`_`". So the variable should be `$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH`. See [Define and modify your variables in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#set-in-script)

The problem is that Linux is case sensitive. It cannot identify the lowercase variable `$env:build_sourceBranch` in Linux. We need to use The **uppercase** variable `$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH` when using Linux agent (`Ubuntu-latest`for example).

So the correct script when using "`Ubuntu-latest`" would be like this:

```
$branch = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH.substring($env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH.indexOf('/', 5) + 1)
```

[image]

Alternately, we can use the `Windows-latest` agent with the `lowercase` variable `$env:build_sourceBranch`.

For example:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $branch = $env:build_sourceBranch.substring($env:build_sourceBranch.indexOf('/', 5) + 1)
      
      Write-Host "branch :" $branch
```

[image]